# Multiline code in Word 2007

Tags: ms-word

I am using word 2007 and am inserting code into the document. I have a style with a fixed-width font and light grey background and all, and I use Notepad++ for syntax highlighting.

My problem is with a "line" of code that is too long to display, so is there a way to auto-insert an arrow symbol at the beginning of a such lines to indicate that it is the same line (kind of like hyphenating, except on long lines instead of long words)

So for e.g. something like this:

public static void foo(String abcdefg, Boolean 123,

→String xyz)

NOTE: Sorry about that, wrong place =D
I created the same post here: https://superuser.com/questions/124306/multiline-code-in-word-2007